# Can`t install app via apt

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Can`t install app via apt, when trying to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` i get the following error

```
Can't exec "/tmp/libssl1.1.config.d7sbrn": Permission denied at /usr/share/perl/5.30/IPC/Open3.pm line 281.
open2: exec of /tmp/libssl1.1.config.d7sbrn configure 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16 failed: Permission denied at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/ConfModule.pm line 59.
dpkg: error: cannot stat pathname '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-4ObeF1/66-libgail-commo    n_2.24.32-4ubuntu4_i386.deb': Too many levels of symbolic links
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: By the way im on a Chromebook and running crouton

Comment: Please use proper formatting and add all relevant information directly to your question, not as comments. You can edit and update your own question anytime.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install? Keep in mind not all software is available for ARM architecture. What errors do you get with `sudo apt update`? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: I just hit this same issue on my ARM chromebook. Fails on installing wine. My machine did a restart on its own, in dev mode, and when it came back the host OS was failing on basic commands like awk because it was trying to use /usr/local/bin 32-bit binaries. I put /usr/bin higher in $PATH and that fixed it. But not inside my debian chroots, it's failing on SOME (not all) apt installs, complaining of too many symlinks.

Comment: It does seem like some link/indirection problem. The /tmp is common to all chroots and is the host OS's /tmp too. I'm on  110.0.5481.112 now for ARM64, which was released recently.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem. Using crouton. The error appears after conventional update and upgrade the system from apt. sudo apt update doesn't give problem. The problem appears with the sudo apt ugrade.

In my case the package is tzdata and it is the ARM branch for sure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160412)